# Modulus of a string

Tags: php

I am in a very puzzling situation. Intially when an user visits a particular page, a popup is shown. User can accept it or decline it. When a user declines it, after 5 page visits, the pop up is again shown to user. This part is working perfectly. When user clicks ok, an ajax call is made and the `SESSION` variable is set to `ok`. Lets say initially `$_SESSION['count'] = 0`. I have two condition statements.

```
if($_SESSION['count']%5 === 0)
{ // do something
}
elseif($_SESSION['count'] === "ok")
{ // do something 
}
```

Now when an user press `ok`, an ajax call is made updating `$_SESSION['count'] = "ok"`. 
When the user again reloads the page, condition `if($_SESSION['count']%5 === 0)` gets true even though `$_SESSION['count']` is now `ok`. Later after much experimenting, i came to know that in php i am able to divide or find modulus `string` by `number` which will result in `zero`. How can i handle this?

Comment: convert the string to a number first?

Comment: `$_SESSION['count'] !== "ok" && $_SESSION['count']%5 === 0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `is_numeric` to check if it is a count or 'ok'

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

```
if(is_numeric($_SESSION['count']) && $_SESSION['count']%5 === 0)
{ // do something
}
elseif($_SESSION['count'] === "ok")
{ // do something 
}
```

Though generally, I would set `ok` to be the value of a different variable in `$_SESSION` as a best practice.  If I was looking at the code I would find it very odd to see something called `count` having a string value.

Comment: thanks a lot.. by the way you missed a Parentheses after `is_numeric($_SESSION['count']` . ;)

Answer (score 3):

PHP is very good at implicit casting.

A solution to your issue is simply re-arrange your `if else` tree.

```
if($_SESSION['count'] === "ok")
{ 
    // do something
}
elseif($_SESSION['count'] % 5 === 0)
{ 
    // do something 
}
```

**Readability**

Something to bare in mind, is that a variable `count` should really contain a value. Perhaps using a different variable might make your code a little less confusing to a reader.

Comment: I think is not correct if set yes instead ok it gives wrong answer

Comment: That's an unrealistic use case @NanheKumar. The system sets the value.

Answer (score 1):

In php, `(int) "some string" == 0`, so check if `$_SESSION['count']` is an integer (e.g. using `is_numeric()`) before doing the modulus.

Answer (score 1):

Check this *working* example. It may help:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['foo'])) {
    $_SESSION['foo'] = 0;
} else {
    $_SESSION['foo']++;
}

var_dump($_SESSION['foo']%3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(is_numeric($_SESSION['count']) AND $_SESSION['count']%5 === 0)
{ // do something
}
elseif($_SESSION['count'] === "ok")
{ // do something 
}
```